How to install Almond (Scala kernel for Jupyter) on Windows 10 using Coursier?
I am trying to install Almond following the instructions on their website. https://almond.sh/docs/quick-start-install
Where I get stuck is this part: $ ./coursier launch --use-bootstrap almond -- --install
When I input it into Git Bash, I get the following error: Unrecognized argument: --use-bootstrap
I tried running the equivalent Windows command in Command Prompt and I got the same issue.

I have Jupyter downloaded using Miniconda
I have two versions of JVM - Initially I tried it with jdk-21.0.5+11 but then I downloaded a version closer to the recommended one (I could not find the exact update of Version 8 they reference): $ java -version 
Output in Git Bash:
openjdk version "1.8.0_432"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_432-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.432-b06, mixed mode)

How can I fix this?
What exactly is bootstrap and why is it needed here? 
In my research I saw Coursier called as cs, why is it ./coursier here?
